# Understanding why voltage and current sources are to be divided by s in the frequency domain

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform

I have been told that whenever I'm drawing a circuit in the frequency (s) domain, the voltage source is to be replaced by V/s and the current source by I/s.

But what exactly is the reason?

When I'm plotting this circuit (replacing s with rad/s), I get that the voltage across R is decreasing as the frequency increase. intuitively, I would say that the voltage or current source should only have a frequency component at s=0, and 0 everywhere else, instead we have that as s approaches 0, the value of the voltage or current source approaches \$ \infty \$ .

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsstTI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It's because the Laplace transform is:
$$A \to \dfrac{A}{s}$$

You assume that the source is applied at t=0:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} A e^{-st} \, dt = \frac{A}{s}$$